# when page initially loads does angular create ''query" property on scope with value "" or undefined when i have ng-model="query" on my element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

i have an input element: 
`<input type="text" ng-model="query" name="query">`. I have not set 'query' property on scope. After the page initially loads:

1) Will angular create `query` property on $scope?

2) If the answer for the 1-st question is `yes`, what will be the value of `query` property on scope, empty string or undefined ?

3) Does the result depend on angular version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Yes - thats exactly what happens

#### 2. undefined (usually you initialize the value in the controller)

#### 3. Not for major releases - you can change between angular versions in the demo below , by clicking the "add library button" - no difference

Here is a working **demo** - http://jsbin.com/mazidutoxi/1/edit?html,js,console,output
Which shows the initial value as a console.log